# Show there is a topologically conjugate

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the subset
$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}X_n$ where $X_n=\{n\}\times [0, 2^{-|n|}]$,
with the metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and define
$f:X\rightarrow X$ by

$ f(n,y):= \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{c l}
    {{(n+1,2y)}} & \text{if $n<0$},\\
    {(n+1,\frac{y}{2})} & \text{if $n\geq0$}.
  \end{array}
\right. $

Also $Y=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{n\}\times [0, 1]$ and $g$ be a  translation on the first coordinate and identity on the second.

In a  paper, author said that there is a homeomorphism $h:X\to Y$ such that $h\circ f= g\circ h$ (without proof).
  I don't understand it. Please help me

Comment: $h(n,y):=(n,2^{|n|}y)$